# wrong number of arguments (0 for 3..6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the mailboxer gem and I am looking to have Questions sent to the Users inbox so they can view and answer the question.

I am receiving a Argument Error `wrong number of arguments (0 for 3..6)`. It points to the line `@message = current_user.send_message.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}",`

I was trying to use the send message instance since the original line of code `@message = current_user.messages.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}"` would submit the Question to the notifications table, but not connect to the conversations table.

Questions Controller:

```
def create
  @question = Question.new(params[:question])
  if @question.save
    #Original code @message = Message.create
    @message = current_user.send_message.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}",
                           #Original code :sender_id
                           :notification_id => @question.sender_id,
                           #Original code :recipient_id
                           :receiver_id => @question.recipient_id,
                           :body => @question.question)

    @question.message = @message
    @question.save
    redirect_to questions_path, notice: 'Your question was saved successfully. Thanks!'
  else
    render :new, alert: 'Sorry. There was a problem saving your question.'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can we see the implementation of the `send_message` method?

Comment: `send_message` is only in the create action of the Questions controller. The other location is inside the Messages controller for create action `current_user.send_message(@recipient, params[:body], params[:subject])`.

Comment: Well that's it, on your comment you use 3 arguments for `send_message` method but in your create method you use `current_user.send_message.new` (using send_message with 0 argument instead of 3..6)

Comment: Ok I understand. I thought I was doing that initially with the `subject`, `notification_id`, `received_id`, and `body`. I will make the changes to see how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `send_message` method (provided by mailboxer gem) requires 3..6 arguments and you are not sending any arguments to it.

Also, looking at your code, it seems like you are trying to save a `message` record for a `question`. So, your `@message` should be set as:

```
@message = current_user.message.new(:subject => "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}",
                           #Original code :sender_id
                           :notification_id => @question.sender_id,
                           #Original code :recipient_id
                           :receiver_id => @question.recipient_id,
                           :body => @question.question)
@question.message = @message
@question.save
```

**Note** that I used `current_user.message.new` instead of `current_user.send_message.new`.

**EDIT**

For using `send_message`, you at least need to pass 3 arguments:

```
send_message(recipient, "Body", "subject")
```

where `recipient` is the person receiving message.

I am not sure why you are chaining `new` method after `send_message`(as it is usually called to `create a new instance of a Class`).

You can call `send_message` as follows:

```
 @message = current_user.send_message(@question.recipient_id, @question.question, "You have a question from #{@question.sender_id}")
```

Comment: I have to use the `send_message` method otherwise it won't create the `conversation_id` that is required and connect to the conversations table. The change you made is something I did previously, which is why I switched to a different method because it did not accomplish what I needed it to.

Comment: I haven't tried the code yet but looking at I'm not seeing how that would work as I would need to specify the body and subject. You just have it the variables without specifying what they're for. So I don't think it would ever connect to the Notifications table with your changes. Unless I am understanding it all wrong.

Comment: Just tried the code and unfortunately as expected it did not work. `undefined method `primary_key' for Fixnum:Class`. It's not creating a `message_id` which is preventing it to submitting to the Notifications table. Also the reason I used `new` method after `send_message` is because I originally had to use that method before to get the Question to send to the Notifications table with the line `@message = current_user.messages.new`. So I thought I should keep the new method since it worked previously.